# API for extract metadata and estimate price of manufacturing

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to know if Autodesk has APIs for the following use cases:

- Extract meta-data from a file (e.g. .stl or .cad files)
- Estimate the price/cost of manufacturing, based on its geometry and materials (such as the Xometry service) and identifying, for a given type of manufacture, the incompatibilities and possible modifications solutions.

In addition, do those services exist as web-interfaces version ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Autodesk Platform Services (APS) provides the web services to extract metadata of the model. The document tells more: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/. As to price and cost, that would be your own business data. As long as you get metadata, you could estimate with the pricing of the vendors and get to know the cost.

Comment: you may also check Autodesk products Fusion Manage or ACC Cost Management if they could be helpful: https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/manage-extensio,  https://learnacc.autodesk.com/page/build-cost-management